# EF Generated Classes & MVVM Project

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I started a project trying to respect a MVVM pattern and  using Entities Framework, however I'm a bit confused regarding the different layers organisation.

Here's my current concern: EF generates POCO classes accordingly to my database structure.
If I understood, those should therefore be my Models.
The interactions with the Database are excluded from the basic MVVM pattern (they belong to an extra Layer - generally called Data from what I've seen -)

However those POCO classes do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which is from the few I've seen / understood of MVVM at the moment, a pretty much keypoint as it's what allows Binding to work.

I've come accross few links regarding this matter, but mostly different answers I read are just getting my head more and more confused.

Coming down to a more concise question: In order to complete POCO classes generated and implement INotifyPropertyChanged, what would be the ideal solution ?

- Consider POCO generated classes as part of an extra Layer, create a wrapper around it as an official Model ?
- Create a second partial class completing the POCO one ?
- Have EF generate classes while implementing this interface ? (I'd rather not for now to be honest, at least while I'm learning. Might be interesting later on though)
- I've also read about some Framework, but being still learning the basics, I'd rather struggle a bit on my own without adding tools for now, that would probably get my head even more confused rather than help at the moment.
- Something else ?

Thanks.

Comment: Go into your T4 files and update them there then keep those T4 files around for your new projects. That way you can keep your POCO's clean, create the standard cruft around the POCO's for data interactions, validity checking, MVVM etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally I'd create ViewModel objects which expose the elements of your POCO objects the UI is interested in - it seems like a fair amount of duplication but it separates your UI from the underlying business/data objects.

Comment: Hey, thanks for you reply.
So if I understand properly, the ViewModel object would instantiate the Model as a private property and only allow to access/modify the properties needed by the View while implementing INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: kind of, in circumstances I've used this the viewModel is usually passed a Model in its constructor but yeah, the UI binds to given attributes which it can change and nothing more.  To be honest it can be tedious exposing Name,Surname,DOB as Name,Surname,DOB but it keeps the separation between the UI binding and underlying model so kinda makes sense...

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I'll leave this as unanswered for a bit waiting for eventual others options.

Comment: cool - all I can say is the extra effort to put the MVVM layers in seems like a real pain, but you do end up with a very clean architecture.  Good luck :)

Comment: I actually have a last question regarding this approach concerning Collections: I'm a bit confused regarding on how to use an ObservableCollection in those conditions. 
If my DB returned for example a List<POCO_Object>, how should I proceed to get my ObservableCollection ? 
Should I reinstantiate each POCO_Object inside the List into wraper objects passing them as parameters and then add those wrapper object created to the ObservableCollection I wish to obtain?
Which Layer would contain a process like this? (It might get a bit off-topic, sorry about that)

Comment: I have a view model of say Order, which contains OrderLines - within the Order view model I grab the orderLines and expose them via a ObservableCollection: - OrderLines = new ObservableCollection<OrderLines>; and then do a foreach over the EF orderlines and add each orderline to the observablecollection as a view model - i.e. foreach (var orderline in orderlines){ OrderLines.Add (new OrderLineViewModel(orderline));  - the UI then binds to the orderlines (observable) view model collection.  which means my underlying objects are replaceable without impacting the UI.  I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Late but thanks again for all the help by the way, finally ended up understanding / putting all the pieces together a little while ago how everything works =p